# How to use a different database host in development vs deployment?

Tags: python, django

I'm new to Python and Django and have over the past few weeks managed to set up my first deployment - a very basic site with user authentication and a few pages, which I hope to fill with content in the next couple of weeks.

I have managed to find the answer to probably 40+ questions I have encountered so far by searching Google / StackOverflow / Django docs etc., but now I have one I can't seem to find a good answer to (perhaps because I don't know how best to search for it): when I develop on my local machine I need my settings.py file to point to the remote database (`'HOST': 'www.mysite.com',`) but when I deploy to a shared hosting service provider they require the use of `localhost` (`'HOST': '',` in settings.py).

Since I host my code on GitHub and want to mirror it to the server, is there a way to resolve this so I don't have to make a manual edit to settings.py each time after uploading changes to the server?

Comment: If there's no way to specify different environment DBs in Django, I'd suggest just taking out of source control the settings.py file

Comment: https://code.djangoproject.com/wiki/SplitSettings has some approaches to this. I personally use something like [this approach](https://code.djangoproject.com/wiki/SplitSettings#Multiplesettingfilesimportingfromeachother).

Comment: Are you sure you want to use your production database when developing? This sounds like a bad idea. Install a local database and use that.

Comment: Thank you all for your input. I decided to go with the approach suggested by Burhan and it works (and seems like a good path forward).

Comment: Daniel, thank you also for the heads up about using a local DB for development. "Production" is a bit misleading for my project since it's really just my first stab at Python/Django dev, and I don't expect to invite anyone other than friends and family to test it. So, not much at stake. But I will look into using two different databases.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can have two copies of your `settings.py` file, one for production and one for development. Whatever you need to be the default, name it as `settings.py`

Just set `DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE` to the *python path* for the file that you would like to use.

So, if your settings files are `myproject/settings.py, myproject/settings_dev.py`; you can then do:

`$ DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE=settings_dev python manage.py shell`

From the `myproject` directory.

Comment: Thank you very much, that's very helpful. I tried it out and it worked. I ran my dev server using `./manage.py runserver --settings=mysite.settings_dev`.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a local_settings.py file which you can put it in .gitignore and include it in the original settings.py. Put every environment sensitive variable in this file (DATABASES, DEBUG, CACHES, MEDIA_URL etc.)

In settings.py:

```
try:
    from local_settings import *
except ImportError:
    pass
```

In .gitignore:

```
*/local_settings.py
```

I recommend you to put a local_settings.py.example next to the setting files which will be in the gitrepo. This way any time you deploy to a new environment you just need to copy this example and change the necessary lines.